# Fuel.upload with form data not sending form data

Tags: android, http, kotlin

Fuel Upload supports optional form data parameter.i passed this parameter and multipart data to upload , but only file upload works form data not associated with request

val formData = listOf(
                "title" to "test",
                "desc" to "test")

```
    FuelRequest = Fuel.upload(URL, method = Method.POST, parameters = formData)
            .dataParts { request, url -> listOf(DataPart(File(URL), "file")) }
```

i logged request object but it only contains.
BTW if we pass empty data part array formdata will be submitted

this is what request obj look like

"Body : --163773469cc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ydu.mp4"
Content-Type:
�������ftypmp42��������is

and without file (empty datapart array)

-"Body : --1637736aeab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"
Content-Type: text/plain

test

--1637736aeab
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="desc"
Content-Type: text/plain

test
--1637736aeab--
"
"Headers : (3)"
Accept-Encoding : compress;q=0.5, gzip;q=1.0
Content-Type : multipart/form-data; boundary=1637736aeab

Comment: please add your answer if you solved this problem